# c++ libtins build errors

Tags: c++, c++11

i'm attempting to compile libtins example from http://libtins.github.io/ and included libtins library. i have some errors that i cant handle with.
I added also pcup library to my project. I'm just learning libtins.

```
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|68|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|89|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|105|error: 'u_short' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|106|error: 'u_short' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|905|error: 'u_short' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|906|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|907|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|908|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\bpf.h|919|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|130|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|131|error: 'u_short' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|132|error: 'u_short' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|134|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|135|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|136|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|169|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|170|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|177|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|178|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|179|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|228|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|244|error: typedef 'pcap_handler' is initialized (use decltype instead)|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|244|error: 'u_char' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|244|error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|244|error: expected primary-expression before 'const'|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|245|error: expected primary-expression before 'const'|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|272|error: 'bpf_u_int32' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|272|error: 'bpf_u_int32' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|299|error: 'pcap_handler' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|299|error: 'u_char' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|300|error: 'pcap_handler' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|300|error: 'u_char' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|301|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|303|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|311|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|317|error: 'bpf_u_int32' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|319|error: 'bpf_u_int32' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|322|error: 'u_char' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|346|error: variable or field 'pcap_dump' declared void|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|346|error: 'u_char' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|346|error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|346|error: expected primary-expression before 'const'|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|346|error: expected primary-expression before 'const'|
C:\Lib\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h|354|error: 'u_int' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\libtins-vs2013-x64-debug\libtins\include\tins\sniffer.h|274|error: 'bpf_u_int32' has not been declared|
C:\Lib\libtins-vs2013-x64-debug\libtins\include\tins\sniffer.h|276|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
C:\Lib\libtins-vs2013-x64-debug\libtins\include\tins\sniffer.h|282|error: 'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type|
||=== Build failed: 47 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

i'm using codeblocks and enabled c++11